# Is this variety a complete intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $M_r$ be the vector space of matrices of size $r\times r$ over $\mathbb C$, and let $X$ be a formal variable, denote by $V_N\subset M_r[X]$ of polynomial of degree at most $N$. Finely let $Z$ be the fiber over $I_r$ of the map $V_N\rightarrow V_{2N}$ given by $$A(X)\rightarrow ^tA(-X)\cdot A(X) $$

Is the subvariety $Z_1\subset Z$ of matrices of determinant $1$ is a complete intersection?

Actually I need just to show that $Z_1$ is reduced. So Is it reduced?

Many thanks

Comment: What is $I_r$ ?

Comment: The identity matrix seen as element of $M_r[X]$

Comment: Have you tried looking at this in a computer algebra system for $r=2$ and $N=2$ or $N=3$? That's $4$ to $12$ variables and all equations are of degree $2$, Macaulay2 can handle this.

Comment: No I didn't. Actually I am not familiar with computer calculation. That will be intersting to see. I believe that one need just to show that the $r(r+1)/2$ quadratic equation generate an ideal with the minimal number of generators is again $r(r+1)/2$ . That I think proves that it is a complete intersection and the result follows by Serr's criterion

Comment: Now also asked on MathOverflow: [Is this variety is reduced?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/275381)

Comment: [This answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives IMO a very reasonable advice regarding cross-posting. And you can find [several discussions about cross-posting on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-posting).

Comment: The map goes from $V_N$ to $V_{2N}$. and of course there is examples where the elements of $Z$  are not just element of $SO(r)$. Yes $t$ means transpose. The fiber $Z$ is over $\pm1$ by the determinant. And I need just those of det equal $1$.